# A problem setting up Canvas - strange error message

Tags: app, error-messages, error, connected-apps, errormessages

Have anyone seen this error message before?

> The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your
>   administrator.
>
> Your support ID is: 9169748803228620297

I am trying to set up a canvas app into an **SSRS** service which is actually and ASPX file on a server. 
I don't know if this error message above is a salesforce message or the SSRS message...

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I have found your answer. It is not necessarily related to your computer, your application, your browser, or salesforce.com. Instead, a firewall known as [BIG-IP ASM](http://www.f5.com/products/big-ip/big-ip-application-security-manager/overview/) has decided that your URL request was invalid, and decided to block it. You should check with your IT department so they can help you resolve it. This information was found under [F5 SOL11029](http://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/11000/000/sol11029.html). The "ID" value is generated by ASM so the administrator can retrieve the details. It may be on your network or on the server's network (I didn't find any easy way to tell which it was).

Comment: Wow, sfdcfox, above and beyond the call of duty!

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox. this is a very good catch! it is exactly our F5 FW :)